# Angular2 ngFor - set selected

Tags: javascript, angular

When a user logs in to my app, it loads the previous UI setup that they were using. To switch between interfaces there is a dropdown that lists all the options that specific user is authorized to use.

I would like the selected option in that list to reflect the previous UI when the page is loading but I'm having trouble coming up with how to set the selected `<option>`

Here is some example code:

```
//User object from DB
var user = {
  username: admin,
  previousUI: 'Build',
  authorizedUI: [{title:'Default'}, {title:'Edit'}, {title:'Build'}]
}
```

html:

```
<form class="navbar-form">
  <label>System: </label>
  <select (change)="systemSelect($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let system of user.authorizedUI" [value]="system.title">
      {{system.title}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

In Angular2 how do I set the `selected` parameter on the option to reflect `user.previousUI`?

I tried adding this:

```
<option *ngFor="let system of user.authorizedUI" [value]="system.title" [selected]="system.title === user.previousUI">
```

But that didn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
<select [ngModel]="user?.previousUI" (change)="systemSelect($event.target.value)">
```